# how to stop a video embedded using react-youtube package when the page is scrolled or a slider is slid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a react web page that embeds youtube videos. Instead of using iframe tag, I have created it using the react-youtube package. I need to pause the video when the page is scrolled, or when the video is in a carousel, pause when the slide is changed. Below is a sample of the code I've written.

```
 const opts = {
   height: '365',
   width: '100%',
   playerVars: {
    autoplay: 0
   }
 };
   <YouTube
    videoId={videoId}
    opts={opts}
    onReady={onReady}
  />
```

I hope my question is clear and thank you in advance. :)